# Filter by part of the slug GhostCMS API

Tags: ghost-blog

I am using NextJS + GhostCMS and @tryghost/content-api
I want to `filter` all pages by part of the slug.
For example, if I have the pages - `slug1-test`, `slug2-test`, `slug3-test`, `slug4`, ...
I want to select all pages with `-test` at the end of the slug.

Then the result of the example will be:
`slug1-test`, `slug2-test`, `slug3-test`.

This is my code:

```
  const posts = await api.posts.browse({
    limit: 10,
    include: ['tags', 'count.posts'],
    order: ['featured DESC', 'published_at DESC'],
    filter: 'slug:[slug1-test]'
  })
```

This code returns a post with a slug `slug1-test`, because there is a post with exactly that slug, but I need to select, only posts with slug, which includes `-test` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem and I managed to solve it:

`filter: "slug:~$'-test'"`

Change your filter property to the above code should filter all tags that end with `-test`. I found this information in their official documentation, take a look at: [Ghost Content Api Filtering](https://ghost.org/docs/content-api/?_ga=2.79410836.189390617.1688186902-352667710.1680261900#filtering).